# How do I pass Python list on Django template and use it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, escaping

I have a python list that has lists inside. I rendered it into Django template to use in my JavaScript. I did `json.dumps(postImages)`, and escaped with `let postImages = {{ postImages|safe }}`. And even tho my lint is giving a warning, it worked!  But the problem is that, there are LISTS, inside of the main list. So whenever I do, `postImages[0].length`, or `postImages[0][0]`, it thinks that it is a string and now a list.

```
<script>
  var postImages = {{ postImages|safe }};
  const divCard = document.querySelector('.card');
  const divDesc = document.querySelector('.description');
  console.log(postImages.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < postImages.length; i++){
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.classList = ['resize_no_stretch', 'images']
      img.setAttribute('src', postImages[i][0]);
      console.log(postImages[i][0])
      divCard.insertBefore(img, divDesc);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Seems you've produced a string, not a list. If you have a proper JSON, then you should simply parse it to use it. If you don't then...I suggest producing JSON, as it's much simpler than trying to consume what amounts to a random format for JS.

Comment: A piece of your template will help understand how exactly you have done this coding, always post a piece of code which will help others to provide a solution for you

Comment: added a code, if any questions, let me know! And thank you for the help guys!

Comment: @MikeYaBoii of course you get a string - that's what you explicitely asked for with `var postImages = '{{ postImages }}';` (what do you think the quotes around `{{ postImage }}` are doing ?).  If you want a javascript list, just follow Valz's suggestion of passing a jsonified list to your template. __This being said__, why are you using JS at all here ? You could just use the template language to do the very same thing at template render time instead.

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing json dumps and escapejs. But it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: OHH!!! IT WORKS NOW YEAHH!!! But there is one more. `{{ postImages }}` is a list. And inside of that list are lists. So when I do, `{{ postImages[0] }}`, it works fine. But when I do `{{ postImages[0][0] }}`, it gives the first character instead of the first element/item from the list.

Comment: nvm, I got it to work now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved now.
What I did was, I imported json on my views and instead of rendering it normally, I `json.dumps()` it.

views.py:

```
import json

postImages = json.dumps(list_of_lists)

return render(request, 'craiglist_clone/results.html', {'postImages' : postImages})
```

django template (craiglist_clone/results.html):

```
let postImages = {{ postImages|safe }}
```

Your lint my give you warning, but it still works!